# attributes in python class

Tags: python, class, attributes, self

I have problem updating attributes in a python class, I give a small example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s=0
        self.procedure()
    def procedure(self):#{{{
        s=self.s
        print s
        self.operation()
        print s
    def operation(self):#{{{                                                                                            
        s=self.s
        s+=1
        self.s=s
        print "o:",self.s
c=myClass()
```

then output

```
0
o: 1
0
```

why the last number is 0 and not 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `procedure` code should read:

```
def procedure(self):#{{{
        s=self.s
        print s
        self.operation()
        # the following line is edited
        print self.s
```

Otherwise, the variable you change (`self.s`) doesn't print.

Answer (score 2):

in `myClass.procedure()`, you create the local name `s` with a value copied from `self.s`, which is `0`. In `myClass.operation()`, you set `self.s` to `1`. But you haven't overwritten your previous copy to `s` in `myClass.procedure()`, so it is still `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing s instead of self.s in the last print.

Comment: @JuanPablo But only until `self.s` gets set to something else.

Comment: @JuanPablo No, it's not. Originally `s` and `self.s` are two names for the same object. But then you change the object that `self.s` is the name for without changing the object that `s` is the name for.

Answer (score 1):

Because `s = self.s` doesn't make `s` another name for "whatever you get by checking `self.s`, always and forever"; it makes `s` another name for "whatever `self.s` currently refers to".

The integer `0` is an object. In the first function, you cause `self.s` and `s` to both refer to that object, and then cause `self.s` to refer to something else (the result of the addition) via another `s` that's local to the other function. The `s` local to the first function is unchanged.